# Is there a way to extract a substring after a specific substring in bash?

Tags: regex, string, bash, awk, split

I receive a .txt file from one of my engineers each morning with the following info:

```
"New York"|NYC|network-details source-group NYC-srcIP dest-group NYC-destIP

"San Francisco"|SF|network-details source-group SF-srcIP dest-group SF-destIP
```

We have a script that runs that can return to us the info similar to below by providing the specified source-group or dest-group:

```
#Calling on source-group
NYC-srcIP|000.000.000.0/32
SF-srcIP|111.111.111.1/32

#Calling on dest-group yields similar info
NYC-destIP|000.000.000.0/32
SF-destIP|111.111.111.1/32
```

The main issue I'm having is doing this for a large amount of data and parsing the string in the .txt file so I can run the script and append it to 2 different files to just get the source-group and dest-groups for all of these locations.

However the .txt has multiple delimiters. Essentially I just want the source-group values (ex:NYC-srcIP) and the dest-group values (ex:NYC-destIP).

Is there an easy way to do this in bash? Preferably pythonic, where I can grab the first space delimited substring after the source-group and dest-group for each line in my .txt file?

Comment: Please add the desired output for the parsed *.txt file. Are `NYC-srcIP` and `NYC-destIP` literal strings or just placeholder for real data?

Comment: And where do the IP-like values that appear in "***the info similar to below***" come from? (i.e. `|000.000.000.0/32`) . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Basic cut / awk should be enough for this, like so:

```
cat ex.txt | sed 's/".*"//' | awk '{print $3,$5}'
```

or

```
cat ex.txt | sed 's/".*"//' | cut -d' ' -f3,5
```

`sed` helps getting rid of the first part inside double quotes, which may contain whitespaces, as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: If the city name doesn't contain a space (ex: "Dallas") then this will not produce the right output. It isn't clear if "New York" and "San Francisco" are the only input cities, I'm only making an observation. You could pass through `awk` first, using `'|'` as delimiter, to isolate the end part of the whole input line, independent of spaces being present/absent in the city name (ex: `awk -F\| '{print $3}'`).

Comment: @kaan you're right, I missed that. I'll edit the answer to make it more consistent.

Answer (score 0):

bash version:

```
pattern="source-group ([^[:space:]]+) dest-group ([^[:space:]]+)"
while read line; do
    if  [[ $line =~ $pattern ]]; then
        echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    fi
done
```

bash test.sh < input